# Gibt es so einen Ausdruck wie "in dem Versuch"

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es im Deutschen den Ausdruck "im Versuch, etwas zu tun"? Also man sagt z.B.

> Das machte er in der Hoffnung, eine gute Stelle zu bekommen.

Geht das auch mit dem Wort "Versuch"?

> Das machte er im Versuch, eine gute Stelle zu bekommen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bisher gibt es diese Wendung nicht (oder wenn sie jemand verwenden sollte, dann an wenig sichtbarer Stelle). Die Wendung ist aber wohlgeformt, und in Texten, in denen ein bisschen Kreativität im Ausdruck erlaubt ist, kannst du sie gerne einsetzen. Ansonsten (z.B. wenn du als Sachbearbeiter im Rathaus für deinen Chef einen Brief schreiben sollst, d.h. wenn deine Kreativität in Fesseln gelegt ist), würdest du eher schreiben:

> Das machte er, um eine gute Stelle zu bekommen.

Denn der Kontext macht ja auch ohne das Wort "Versuch" klar, dass es hier um einen Versuch geht.

Typisch, wenn auch sehr hölzern (eben Amtsstubendeutsch) wäre noch:

> Das macht er im Bemühen, eine gute Stelle zu bekommen.

Dann gibt es noch "beim Versuch", aber dessen Bedeutung ist etwas anders. Hier geht es um einen konkreten (in Zeit und Raum plazierten) Versuch:

> Beim Versuch, die Straße zu überqueren, wurde die Ente von einem Lastwagen überfahren.